# execute function after Fullcalendar eventAfterAllRender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to execute a function after I have given the Fullcalendar a new source and it has rerendered. There is a way to manipulate the calendar dynamically. But `eventAfterAllRender` dont seem to be supported. 
My Code:

```
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', items);
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', firstDayOfWeek);

            jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('eventAfterAllRender ', function () {
                if (!$calender.is(':visible')) {
                    $calender.fadeTo(1000, 1);
                }
            });
```

I get this error message from the above code:

> 'eventAfterAllRender ' is an unknown FullCalendar method.

If you  also feel that I  can do all this in a better way, please tell me. I want to learn.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: There is a space in `'eventAfterAllRender '`

Comment: Because it is an event, not a method. belongs in your config object

Comment: That explains it. Do you know how i shall i use it for my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is about typo. try this:

```
$("calendar").fullCalendar({
    eventAfterAllRender: function(){
        $("#button").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: tried it, get this error now `eventAfterAllRender is not defined`

Comment: hmm, which version of fullcalendar do you use?

Comment: Solved it. used your code in the initial decleration of full calender, where I keep all the settings. Thought I could use it dynamically. Silly me. Now it `fadeTo()  `.everytime I make adjustments dynamically.